# The petals of rose flowers are burned

Tags: diseases, roses

I have  a question about my rose flowers.
I have two rose flowers which are planted in the garden, one of them is in the sun and another is in shadow during the day.

The following  problem is ocuured  for both annually .

the petals of Both flowers are burned or get browned  as you see in the taken photo.

The question is what's the reason of this issue?

[image]

Comment: have you had a lot of wet weather in the last fortnight or so?